# How to make Next.js debugging useful?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js

[From the Next.js VSCode debugging page](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging), I got the following `launch.json`.

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After running the full stack option, Next.js starts like any old `npm run dev`. The problem is that the debugging isn't very useful. In my debug terminal I have it selected so that there are breakpoints on caught exceptions. In Python applications (where my debugging experience lies), VSCode pauses on the exact line number whenever there is an exception and gives a useful, understandable error.

With Next.js, the breakpoint gives me a complicated, general error that leads to some random Next.js source code. This has next to no meaning for me.

For example, I got a promise rejected error. This is likely from a request I made that was handled with `.catch` using Axios. Next.js pointed me to the following deeply nested file.

`\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\on-demand-entry-handler.js`

On line 202 it caught an error in code which I have never seen before. Upon unpausing the breakpoint, it leads to more of these errors.

How can I make Next.js debug for me more efficiently? I want more clear, understandable errors, that lead me to specific lines of code that I actually wrote.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

> I have it selected so that there are breakpoints on caught and uncaught exceptions

Unchecking "Caught Exceptions" will likely lead to the debug behavior you seek.

#### Explanation

It appears you may have misunderstood what checking "Caught Exceptions" does. Enabling breakpoints on **caught exceptions** means the debugger will pause on **all** caught exceptions: your code and all JavaScript dependencies are included (including files like `\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\on-demand-entry-handler.js`)

> On line 202 it caught an error in code which I have never seen before. Upon unpausing the breakpoint, it leads to more of these errors.

This is expected behavior, as try/catch statements are standard practice in JavaScript to catch unexpected behavior and errors, and therefore the debugger pauses on all of these statements as long as Caught Exceptions is checked. A catch statement implies an **expected** error occurred, so pausing on it may not make sense in your debug case!

Breaking on **uncaught** exceptions is more likely to pause on meaningful errors and exceptions, meaning that an **unexpected** error was thrown and not caught inside of a try/catch statement. It's likely that dependencies will not have any uncaught exceptions (if they do then it may be considered a bug), hence allowing the debugger to catch mistakes mainly within your code.

Comment: Looking back, I probably shouldn't have mentioned that I had uncaught exceptions checked, as it made my question more complicated than it should be.

Next.js debugging remains frustrating whether uncaught is checked or not. The fact that uncaught exceptions was checked was just a pedantic detail specific to my use case. I've edited my post to reflect this, but I thank you for your input anyways.